# how to create a text file using php where the records should be from mysql

Tags: php, file

Could any one explain me how to create a text file using php where the records should be from mysql

Comment: Try searching Google for "php mysql tutorial".

Comment: See SitePoint's [Server-side Coding PHP & MySQL Tutorials](http://articles.sitepoint.com/category/php-tutorials) or the [chapter on Databases in Practical PHP](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/9/0/0)

Comment: sorry. I mean to say that how to create a text file using php where the records should be from mysql

Comment: *(reference)* [`file_put_contents` — Write a string to a file](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) open a file in write mode:

```
   $myFile = "testFile.txt";
   $fo = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
```

2) Write mysql query and fetch its data

```
   $data_query=mysql_query("SELECT name,age from table");
   while($data=mysql_fetch_array($data_query))
   $stringData.="Name: ".$data['name']." Age:".$data['age']."\n";
```

3) Write data into the file

```
   fwrite($fo, $stringData);
```

4) Close file

```
   fclose($fo);
```

Comment: hi.. thanks nik. its working fine. But how to merge multiple records. thanks for the answer

Comment: Or write the data directly (using multiple fwrite) to the file without concatenating in php if you have larger data sets.

Comment: It depends on your data, check my edit done for the data of user's name and age, the .(dot) after $stringData will append multiple records Also the point made by Eiko is correct, its just the way you like to write your code

Comment: is it possible to create a table structure and store the data

Comment: Then you need to create .csv file rather then txt file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fh   = fopen('games_set_88.php',"w");//php path

$extend_q  = mysql_query('SELECT * from mod_games_set');

$row_count = mysql_num_rows($extend_q);

$col_count = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query('describe mod_games_set'));

$data_str  = "<?php \n"."    $"."mod_extend_type = array(\n";

$startout  = 1;

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($extend_q)){
$startin = 1;
foreach($row as $key =>$value){
if( $startin<$col_count){
    if($startin == 1){
        $data_str .= "      '".$value."'=>array('".$key."'=>'".$value."',";
         }else{
            if($startin < $col_count-1) 
                $data_str .= "'".$key."'=>'".$value."',";
            else 
               $data_str .= "'".$key."'=>'".$value."')";
            }
        $startin++;
    }
}

if($startout < $row_count) $data_str .= ",";
    $data_str .= "\n";
    $startout++;
}
$data_str .=" );\n?>";
fwrite($fh,$data_str);
fclose($fh);
```